# Related input value with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have couple of input which has placeholder than whenever I focus on the input I want to get placeholder value with alert or inside a div.
my codes (example);
html

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone:">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email">
```

and my js files:

```
var plchold = ('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder');
$("<div class='field-label'><p>"+plchold+"</p></div>").prependTo(".wrap-field");
```

But it just given me first placeholder value for all input.

I know it must be with `$(this)` but I don't know how :)

Comment: How are you iterating over inputs?

Comment: like this 
var plchold = ('input[type=text]').attr('placeholder');
var plchold.$(this); @MilindAnantwar

Comment: that wont work. posted answer below. do check it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
$('input[type=text]').focus(function(){
  var plchold = $(this).attr('placeholder');
  $("<div class='field-label'><p>"+plchold+"</p></div>").prependTo(".wrap-field");
});
```

Comment: how about without focus without event is it impossible ? I mean I have 2 rows name and input
name | input[text] 
and I want to get name filed from input value for each input value let me see;

<div class="wrap">
 <div class="name"></div>
<div class="input-text"><input type="text" placeholder="Name"></div>
</div>
name area must written by placeholder value for each wrap is it impossible ?

Comment: @yedincifirat please explain more your point as it is not clear

Answer (score 1):

you should loop through inputs to get placeholder for each one

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    var plchold = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    $("<div class='field-label'><p>"+plchold+"</p></div>").prependTo(".wrap-field");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over input elements and use iteration context `this` to target them in each iteration:

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(){
    var plchold = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    $("<div class='field-label'><p>"+plchold+"</p></div>").prependTo(".wrap-field");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("input[type=text]").focus(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('placeholder'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" placeholder="Phone:">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email">
```